# How to : customize messages on an advanced combo box (GXT 3)?

Tags: gxt

I am using an advanced comboBox like this one : http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:advancedcombobox.

I would like to change the label displayed at the bottom of the result list : `Displaying 1 - 10 of 274`.

How is it possible? I saw that [PagingToolBar](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.0/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/toolbar/PagingToolBar.html) exposes its Messages via getters/setters but I don't know how to get it from the ComboBox.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it :

```
ComboBox.getCell().getPagingToolBar()
```